# Extract values around key words in a character string

Tags: r, string, character

I am looking for a model of machine learning able to detect numbers located around key words in long character string :

```
“R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)--"Feather Spray"Copyright(C)2018TheRFoundationbananas12forStatisticalComputingPlatform:-darwin15.6.0(64-bit)Risfreesoftwareandcomesapples84withABSOLUTELYNOWARRANTY.Youarewelcometoredistributeitundercertainconditions.Type'liceoranges67nse()'or'licence()’fordistributiondetails."
```

The idea here is to extract :

```
apples 84 
bananas 12
oranges 67
```

Is there any R package able to realize this task ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing package per se, but you can just as easily build an alternation of matching fruit words, and then do a regex search in your input string for all matches:

```
fruits <- c("apples", "bananas", "oranges")
regex <- paste0("(", paste(fruits, collapse="|"), ")\\s*\\d+")
input <- "R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)--\"Feather Spray\"Copyright(C)2018TheRFoundationbananas12forStatisticalComputingPlatform:-darwin15.6.0(64-bit)Risfreesoftwareandcomesapples84withABSOLUTELYNOWARRANTY.Youarewelcometoredistributeitundercertainconditions.Type'liceoranges67nse()'or'licence()’fordistributiondetails."
regmatches(input, gregexpr(regex, input))[[1]]

[1] "bananas12" "apples84"  "oranges67"
```

Note that the regex being used here is:

```
(apples|bananas|oranges)\\s*\\d+
```

This matches one of the fruit terms, followed by optional space, and one or more digits.  You may add more fruits to the input vector to expand this regex.